# Imagemagick loses gradient on image on Ubuntu

Tags: svg, png, imagemagick, gradient

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.
I have installed ImageMagick from the latest source package. Here is the output from "convert -version"

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-6 2012-04-19 Q16 http: // www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

I am trying to convert an svg into a png which works great unless I have a gradient on some part of the image.

Here is the command I am running:

```
convert RedPoweredByPenguins.svg redpenguin.png
```

Here is the SVG: http://gamepsychos.com/penguinCheckers/redPenguin.svg

And here is the png it creates: http://gamepsychos.com/penguinCheckers/redpenguinfail.png

When I run this same command on Fedora 16, I don't lose the gradient. I think maybe one of the libraries ImageMagick uses is not the same but I'm not sure. Anyone have any ideas?

The version output on the working system is:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-6 2012-04-19 Q16 http: //www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings or any different output in the faulty system?

Comment: By the way, whilst I presume ImageMagick should be able to handle this, I've had some excellent results rendering SVG -> PNG programmatically using Inkscape, in command line mode.

Comment: Also: that looks like a very complex document for such a simple image. Are you sure that all of those elements are required? Also, save it as a standard SVG document (i.e. without the Inkscape extensions) and ensure it validates against the 1.1 DTD.

Comment: I don't get any output on the faulty system. I am actually writing a script that I want to take arbitrary SVGs and flatten them into one PNG.

Comment: I tried using a plain svg document and have the same results.

Comment: What is the version string for ImageMagick on the working system? Post it into your question, if you would.

Comment: They are both using the same version, added to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some additional research, I found that the SVG delegate that the "faulty" machine was not using the same as the one on the working machine.

To correct this, I installed rsvg.

```
apt-get install librsvg2-bin
```

Then I change ImageMagick's configuration to use rsvg rather than the default delegate.

Comment: I wasn't aware this could be done! Does this fix the problem? (If so, don't forget to tick your own answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just got exactly the same as your "faulty" output on my Mac, with this ImageMagick:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-0 2012-03-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP OpenCL
```

So, I think the SVG file is incorrect. Try validating it?

Comment: It passed here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgamepsychos.com%2FpenguinCheckers%2FPlain.svg&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3

But has 3 warnings.