# ImageMagick SVG to PNG conversions removes gradients

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to allow users to upload an SVG image through a CMS and generate a fallback PNG so that when the CMS displays the content on the front end the PNG fallback is shown for older browsers.

The problem is that when I upload an SVG the PNG output is a bit off, gradients seem to be missing as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: SVG on the left PNG on the right]

In these tests I'm just using ImageMagick commandline as below but have tried it through the CMS upload using Imagick with the same result.

```
convert gallardo.svg gallardo.png
```

Imagick version sets background to transparent as suggested in [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php) but PNG output is the same as commandline.

```
class ResampleSvgUpload extends DataExtension {

    function onAfterUpload() {
        if($this->isSvg()){
            $this->resample();
        }
    }

    function onAfterWrite() {
        if($this->isSvg()){
            $this->resample();
        }
    }

    function isSvg() {
        $extension = strtolower($this->owner->getExtension());
        return ($extension == 'svg') ? true : false;
    }

    function resample() {
        $original = $this->owner->getFullPath();
        $resampled = $original . '.png';    
        $imagick = new Imagick($original);
        $imagick->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
        $imagick->setImageFormat('png');
        $imagick->writeImage($resampled);
    }
}
```

I'm using:

- ImageMagick 6.9.0-3
- Imagick 3.1.0RC2
- PHP 5.3.29
- OSX Yosemite 10.10

Comment: If the answer below doesn't help, can you post the result of the output with the verbose command enabled, as well as post an example pdf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235426/imagemagick-loses-gradient-on-image-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageMagick does not do the conversion of SVG itself, instead it delegates that task to a 3rd party program. You can find which program is being used by adding the `-verbose` option to the convert command.

The issue will almost certainly be being caused by a bug in that underlying program - and will hopefully go away when you upgrade to a newer version of it.

Comment: This resolved the issue - I reinstalled ImageMagick with "brew reinstall imagemagick --with-librsvg librsvg --use-rsvg" and conversion now works correctly

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, It didn't work at once for me. I had to do 'brew reinstall imagemagick --use-rsvg' to get it working. Works like charm now!

Comment: An old question and answer but still very current.  This helped me on Ubuntu 16 with inkscape v0.91 -> v0.92.  Excellent.